# Would you mind sorting through a few Beginner SQL invoice database creation questions?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relationships

I'm somewhat new to SQL.

I need to make an invoice that can be queried to create a document that looks something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the crow's foot diagram I made:

[image: crow's foot diagram]

I'm not sure if the customer shipping and billing address should be a separate entity. I'm also not so sure about the tblProductLine relationship to the tblItem and tblInvoice. Did I diagram it right?

Did I match the schema and setup the relationships correctly? Also, Could someone explain when foreign keys are necessary ? (since I wasn't sure where to put them) I'm assuming they go at the end of the 1 to many relationships to reference the previous table that called it, but I'm not sure... which tables need a foreign key?

Anyways... any help or comments would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts in random order:

1. Your crow's foot is on the wrong site for some entities. An employee can have several invoices, but I assume that an invoice is "owned" by one employee.
2. Why does your `Employee` have an `InvoiceID`? They can certainly have more than one invoice?
3. Consider adding an `Address`-table and give your customer a `ShippingAddress` and a `BillingAddress` (optional), both referencing `Address`.
4. What is the difference between `Quantity` and `Amount` in `tblProductLine`?
5. Where do you get the price for *Shipping and Handling* from?
6. You're storing the size in an extra field, but not the color. Color could be part of the `ItemDescription`, but then you can't really find out that the red and the blue *Jag Something* are the same product
   Depending on your requirements, it might be better to normalize that table and move `size` and `color` into a sub-table. If you need to rename a product, you only change one record instead of many.

Answer (score 1):

Typically ORDERS and INVOICES though very closely related are decoupled; you're conflating them into a single entity.

The CUSTOMER places an ORDER for one or more PRODUCTS.  That generates the Order Header and Order Detail. The merchant issues an INVOICE referencing the Order. But in a very simple mom-and-pop operation you could dispense with ORDERS and let the INVOICE entity represent the order.

```
        ORDER|INVOICE DETAIL
        id  int PK
        headerid foreign key references INVOICEHEADERS or ORDERHEADERS *mutatis mutandis*
        productid foreign key references PRODUCTS(id)
        quantity
        extendedamount
```

Foreign keys are necessary because they prevent things like creating an order for a product that does not exist, or invoicing a customer that does not exist.  They ensure that the database row contains no impossibilities.

Typically you'd have CUSTOMERADDRESSES as a separate table that refers back to CUSTOMERS.  A customer can have one or more addresses.

Whenever an entity can "have one or more of X" that's a sign that you need a separate table to capture the Xes.